# Making a class remove itself

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I am making a program using Tkinter that will create a list of events. I used a class to make an event. If I click the **Add Event** button (second script shown), it creates a new instance of the class, lengthening the list. However, I also want to be able to remove events from the list. I am trying to attach a remove button to each class that, when clicked, will delete the class. This is my code from the class script (`classes.py`):

```
from Tkinter import *

class agendaEvent:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.frame.pack(side=TOP)
        self.name = Entry(self.frame)
        self.name.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.time = Entry(self.frame, width=10)
        self.time.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)
        self.label1 = Label(self.frame, text="Event Name")
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label2 = Label(self.frame, text="Minutes")
        self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.remove = Button(self.frame, text="Remove", command=agendaEvent.remove)
        self.remove.grid(row=1, column=3)

    def remove(agendaEvent):
        del agendaEvent
```

When I press the remove button, I get the error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: unbound method remove() must be called with agendaEvent instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

How can I call the instance of `agendaEvent`? Or is there a better way of going about this? This is the code for the main script (`main.py`):

```
from Tkinter import *
import classes


def addEvent():
    classes.agendaEvent(root)

root = Tk()

addEventButton = Button(root, text="Add Event", command=addEvent)
addEventButton.pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The class can't remove itself; that functionality needs to be in whatever is *holding* the list. Also, using a name other than `self` for the first parameter to an instance method is unconventional and therefore a bad idea.

Comment: Define your remove method with self. `def remove(self, agendaEvent):`

Comment: @Valijon the OP is effectively trying to `del self`, I think.

Comment: This is essentially what I want the program to look like

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/XlLX7uT.png?1

Comment: @JohnHall yes, I understood that; it doesn't change the fact that *the class can't remove itself*. It could call some method on its `master` to get itself removed, I suppose.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so how could I go about doing this? I'm fairly new to programming. Could I achieve the same effect in a different manner? If so, how? Also, is there a way I  could assign a unique variable to each instance of the class I call?

Comment: *"how could I go about doing this?"* is much too broad a question for SO. *"Could I achieve the same effect in a different manner?"* - yes, as I've said you could provide that functionality in the `master`. *"is there a way I could assign a unique variable to each instance of the class I call?"* - yes, put them in a dictionary so you can access them by key.

Comment: @jonrsharpe my question is not "CAN I", its "HOW can I". Is there somewhere I could look that would explain how to add this functionality in the master? Or could you explain it?

Comment: Yes, and (as I've already said) *"HOW can I"* is **too broad for this site**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am sorry if I'm not communicating myself properly. I have no idea how to assign a button to each instance of the class that would remove it in the master. As I have said, I am fairly new to coding and I don't have a full grasp of everything yet. Could you perhaps direct me to a site that would give me the information needed

Answer (score 0):

You can remove labels and other widgets (not sure all) with .destroy(). If you store the instances of the class in some way you can forget or destroy them, but if the instance is just an instance then I don't see your problem (read, I can't help you). If you want to learn how to build GUIs with Tkinter you should check out sentdex's videos on the subject on youtube.

This is how I make tkinter widgets with buttons like I think you are trying to do:

1. I make a counter variable that counts how many objects my list contains.
2. I make a button that point to a method or a function that makes a label that contains the info I want it to contain, e.g. .get()
   something from an entry box.
3. The function then adds one entry to the counter variable.
4. Then I make a button that points to a method or function that destroys the last label, I use the counter variable as index to know
   what label to destroy.
5. I then subtract one from the counter variable

I use a dictionary to keep my labels and other widgets in order, e.g. by using a counter variable as key.

Example:

```
from tkinter import *

class MyEvent("something tkinter"):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        "here you need some tkinter code to make a frame or something to put your widgets in"

        self.mycounter = 0
        self.myEventLabel = {}
        addButton = Button(parent, text="add event", command=addEvent).pack()
        destroyButton = Button(parent, text="remove last event",          command=removeEvent).pack()

    def addEvent(self):
        self.myEventLabel[self.mycounter] = Label("Here goes the options you want)
        self.mycounter+=1

    def removeEvent(self):
        self.mycounter-=1
        self.myEventLabel[self.mycounter].destroy()
```

Hope this helped, if I missed the point, then in my defense I'm not a programmer, just someone who needs to use programming as a means to an end. Again, Sentdex's videos covers alot of tkinter, check them out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the class instance to remove it.  Below, addEvent() has been changed to catch the return from calling the class, and that instance is attached to the button so the button knows which instance to destroy.  This would better if all of the code was wrapped in classes but I am following the code you posted above which is likely just a simple example.

```
from Tkinter import *
from functools import partial

class agendaEvent:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.frame.grid()
        self.name = Entry(self.frame)
        self.name.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.time = Entry(self.frame, width=10)
        self.time.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)
        self.label1 = Label(self.frame, text="Event Name")
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label2 = Label(self.frame, text="Minutes")
        self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1)

def addEvent(master):
        this_instance=agendaEvent(master) 
        ## add the button to the frame created by this function call
        ## and not to the root, so it also is destroyed
        rem = Button(this_instance.frame, text="Remove", bg="lightblue",
                     command=partial(remove_class, this_instance))
        rem.grid(row=6, column=0)

def remove_class(instance):
    ## destroys the frame created by the instance
    ## i.e. self.frame in agendaEvent
    instance.frame.destroy()  
    instance=""          ## reassigns "instance" so the class is garbage collected

root = Tk()

addEventButton = Button(root, text="Add Event", command=partial(addEvent, root))
addEventButton.grid(row=5, column=0)

Button(root, text="Exit", bg="orange", command=root.quit).grid(row=99, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So I am having a bit of trouble with the code here. First off, I am not totally sure I understand partial. From what I have researched, it seems like it is the same as calling the function as addEvent(root), which I assume is not possible in the button. However, when I try to run this code, it throws out this error:

"TypeError: addEvent() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)"    

Any suggestions?

Comment: Nevermind, I was being a complete idiot. Just ignore that last comment, the problem is fixed. Thanks a lot for your help, I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your class as shown below will fix the error you're currently getting. It's caused by the fact that the handler specified with a `command` keyword argument passed to the `Button` constructor is always called without any arguments. Fixing that with a `lambda` function then exposes another problem, which is that you've named both the `Button` instance and the method you want to associated it with the same thing – `remove` – so I renamed it to `remove_button`.

```
from Tkinter import *

class agendaEvent:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.frame = Frame(master, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.frame.pack(side=TOP)
        self.name = Entry(self.frame)
        self.name.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.time = Entry(self.frame, width=10)
        self.time.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5)
        self.label1 = Label(self.frame, text="Event Name")
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label2 = Label(self.frame, text="Minutes")
        self.label2.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.remove_button = Button(self.frame, text="Remove",
                                    command=lambda: self.remove())
        self.remove_button.grid(row=1, column=3)

    def remove(self):  # by convention the first argument to a class
        del self       # method is usually named "self"
```